# How to serialize the recorded audio into XML and deserialize back to play in c#/xaml metro app?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, audio, microsoft-metro

I am following [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-capture-sample-adf87622) media capture sample for my app. Now I don't want to save the audio in MP3 in a folder but I want to serialize that MP3 file in XML and then back want to de-serialize that XML to play the recorded MP3 file. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What is the point of storing in an XML file?  It seems completely pointless as it's just binary data.  That said, binary data is generally converted into text using Base64 encoding.

Comment: I have done base64 encoding. The mp3 file size of 986 KB was encoded in 1.28 MB file. Isn't it feasible ?

Comment: All you would have to do now is just write the Base64 data to your XML file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to do it this way rather than saving the RAW MP3 data. However, the process would look like this:

1. base64 encode your MP3 data
2. store the base64-encoded data in an XML document. The base64 data can be treated as any string. eg:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <root>
       <mp3>...BASE64DATA....</mp3>
   </root>
   ```
3. save the file to the disk.

To get the MP3 data back, just reverse the processess.